# Replace only first occurrence with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that comes from HTML without tags but with escaped symbols, like:

```
abc&symbol1;def&symbol2;ghi&symbol3;jkl...
```

In JavaScript or TypeScript, how can I replace all sequences like `&symbolN;` with one fixed character like `X` so I get:

```
abcXdefXghiXjkl...
```

(by the way, the target is to get the length of a string with distinct HTML escaped characters like `&pound;` so that each one of them is counted like one character)

**Update**: maybe I've not explained accurately: symbol1, symbol2,... do not mean that "symbol" string repeats, but completely distinct symbols that DO NOT repeat, e.g. "abc£def ghi€..." So no way to use a repeating textual pattern like "&symbol;"

Comment: Do you know regex? By the way, you want to replace only 1st occurence (as per title) or all occurrences (description)?

Comment: Regex is your friend here `&symbol\d+;`

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, only first? Or all? Have you tried to search for a solution, before asking?

Answer (score 2):

Just to calculate length, you can cheat, as you say:

```
html.replace(/&[^;]+;/, 'X').length
```

To convert HTML into text properly, one should use a HTML parser, not regexp. For example, in browser,

```
let e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = html;
let text = e.textContent;
```